Why does my transistor not turn on?
I’m currently trying to design a circuit that will turn on a fuel pump when given B+ (fused or SW 12 VDC), and then give a ground signal out of pin 6 when a set time delay has passed. But the transistor never turns on. Everything else seems to function, to include the potentiometer/Zener diode function, but no such luck on the transistor. Is there something I'm missing as a relatively novice designer? I'm wondering if I'm having some current issue with the TIP 122 not receiving enough current.
Pin-out for the terminal block:
1 - Fused B+
2 - SW B+
3 - Pump Output
4 - unused
5 - RMT
6 - GRND


Can you please measure base-emitter voltage and collector-emitter voltage?

never turns on IRL, on in a simulation? I notice several "connection dots" in red.

Never turns on IRL. I can manually actuate the TDSA and get the desired result.
I will measure the voltages when I go back into work Monday. I’ll keep you posted.

Pin 6 appears to be wired directly to GND. The delay would thus be rather brief. Is the supply 12V/13.8VDC?

Why would that make the delay brief? I was tying all the grounds off to a common ground of the genset it would be attached to. Is this not a correct use of ground?
It is 12-13.8VDC. Battery voltage for a generator.

Hey All, just measured my Base emitter, and collector emitter voltages. My Base Emitter voltage was ~7VDC, and my collector emitter voltage was 4VDC. Shouldn't these be opposite in terms of magnitude?
